# CMD Batch file GDAL - extending the for /f loop to escape temporary files

Tags: batch-file, for-loop, cmd, gdal

After struggling for a while, I figured how I could extract coordinates for each georeferenced jpg file from gdalinfo. My problem is that I can't figure out how to do all the operations without the need for temporary files. The extra lines and temporary files add several hours of processing time.

How to "merge" these operations?? no temp files, and only passing through each file once > the.mmm Would be very grateful for any help!

```
for /R %%g in (*.jpg) do echo 0.000 0.000 > %%~png.mmt

for /R %%g in (*.jpg) do gdalinfo %%g | findstr /i /C:"size is" /C:"lower left" /C:"upper right" >>%%~png.mmt

for /R %%g in (*.jpg) do echo 0.000 >> %%~png.mmt

for /R %%a in (*.mmt) do (for /F "tokens=1,2 delims=SizeisLowrftUpRgh,() " %%G IN (%%a) DO @echo %%G %%H >> %%~pna.mmm)
```

The result looks like this:

```
0.000 0.000 
1931 1448 
317600.000 6543562.880 
317677.240 6543620.800 
0.000
```

`gdalinfo | findstr` extracts the lines I'm looking for. The "for /f tokens" strips away text from those lines.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had already done most of the work :-)

```
@echo off
for /r %%F in (*.jpg) do (
  echo 0.000 0.000
  for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=SizeisLowrftUpRgh,() " %%A in (
    'gdalinfo "%%F" ^| findstr /i /c:"size is" /c:"lower left" /c:"upper right"'
  ) do echo %%A %%B
  echo 0.000
)>"%%~pnF.mmm"
```

Comment: Great! You made me finally understand the logic : ) the only thing missing was a ^ before the |. At least to get it working for me.

Comment: @user3023461 - Yep, I forgot the `^`, thanks. Don't forget to accept an answer if it fully answers your question to your satisfaction. Simply click on the check mark near the upper left corner of the answer. That action lets others know the question has been answered,  awards you 2 reputation points, and awards the answer poster 15 rep points. Only one answer may be accepted per question. Once you reach 15 rep, you will be able to up vote as many answers as you find useful, even answers to other peoples questions.